Converting HSC g, r, i, z to Gaia G-band Magnitude for Quasars
I am working on a project that requires converting magnitudes from the HSC (Hyper Suprime-Cam of Subaru) photometric system g, r, i, z to the Gaia G-band magnitude.
The HSC system uses filters based on the SDSS g', r', i', z' filters. Additionally, I found conversion formulas between the SDSS photometric system and Gaia G band provided in a Gaia paper, as shown here:

Can I directly treat HSC g, r, i, z magnitudes as equivalent to SDSS g', r', i', z' magnitudes for conversion purposes?
Does the conversion between photometric systems depend on the type of sources? For instance, would the conversion formulas differ for quasars compared to stars, or are they source-independent, allowing me to apply the same formulas to quasar magnitudes? If the provided formulas are not appropriate for quasars, could you suggest the correct approach or provide the appropriate formulas for converting magnitudes between systems for quasars?

Please don't downvote without an explanation, especially not for new contributors.
